# Is template qualifier required in class template non-dependent member variables?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang

I got the compile error "error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'foo' as a dependent template name" when I compile the following code on commented line. (test4)

All other parts of codes are successfully compiled.

```
#include <tuple>

struct my {
    template <typename T>
    void foo() {}
};

void test1() {
    my m;
    auto tr = std::forward_as_tuple(m);
    auto& t0 = std::get<0>(tr);
    t0.foo<int>();
}

template <typename T>
struct test2 {
    void method() {
        my m;
        auto tr = std::forward_as_tuple(m);
        auto& t0 = std::get<0>(tr);
        t0.foo<int>();
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct test3 {
    void method() {
        m.foo<int>();
    }
    my m;
};

template <typename T>
struct test4 {
    void method() {
        auto tr = std::forward_as_tuple(m);
        auto& t0 = std::get<0>(tr);
        t0.foo<int>();          // error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'foo' as a dependent template name
        t0.template foo<int>(); // OK
    }
    my m;
};

template <typename T>
struct test5 {
    void method() {
        std::tuple<my> tr = std::forward_as_tuple(m);
        auto& t0 = std::get<0>(tr);
        t0.foo<int>();
    }
    my m;
};

template <typename T>
struct test6 {
    void method() {
        auto tr = std::forward_as_tuple(m);
        my& t0 = std::get<0>(tr);
        t0.foo<int>();
    }
    my m;
};


int main() {
    test1();
    test2<int>().method();
    test3<int>().method();
    test4<int>().method();
    test5<int>().method();
    test6<int>().method();
}
```

`test4` is a class template but m is non dependent type.

I tried to compile gcc and clang. gcc 7.1.0 dosen't report errors, but clang 4.0 and later report the compile error.

Error

https://wandbox.org/permlink/HTSBJMD2kXwfWObl (clang 4.0)
https://wandbox.org/permlink/BcUT8gtaFxwC41c5 (clang HEAD)

No error

https://wandbox.org/permlink/GjIvZa3i5HB8uh6w (gcc 7.1.0)

Which is correct behavior?

Comment: @StoryTeller, thanks for the comment. Why test3 and test5 don't need template keyword?

Comment: You know, scratch what I said. I see now that I completely ignored the other tests. Great question.

Comment: Not the error. In test 5, when you do `std::forward_as_tuple(m)`, you obtain a `std::tuple<my &>`, not a `std::tuple<my>`. It doesn't change the result anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to agree with your suspicion. This is indeed a clang bug.

The `template` is required if and only if `t0` is a dependent name. In particular, it's required if `t0` depends on `T`. And that's the `T` in `test4<T>`.

Now, `t0` depends on `my m`, and there's a `my::foo<T>`, but that's an unrelated `T` in a different scope. Additionally, `t0` doesn't depend on `my::foo<T>`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I searched clang Bugzilla. Then I found similar bug. https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17401 I added a comment including the link to this post.